# Distinguish public folder on nginx server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx-reverse-proxy, mern

I am running MERN stack app on Nginx server in ubuntu. Currently I have deployed successful both of them, but got stuck in distinguishing public folder. Here is my Nginx server config
[image]

As you can see API route goes to node.js, but cannot access node.js public folder. How can I config both react and node.js public folder accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people assign the public folder from express, not nginx. It would be something like this

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

And this will serve static files from your /public folder in the express app. You can read more about it here if you want

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I need to assign my react.js in node.js not in nginx. Thanks for the assist by the way.

Comment: bad practice is to assign public folder from express